# Calling the methods of two object on a single onclick

Tags: android

**MAIN ACTIVITY OF AMAZING FACTS**

```
package com.example.user.amazingfacts;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView showtext;
private Button showbutton;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private Amazingnote Amazingnote=new Amazingnote();
private Colorwheel colorwheel=new Colorwheel();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showtext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.showtext);
        showbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.showbutton);
        showbutton.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
String fact= Amazingnote.getFact();
showtext.setText(fact);

int color=colorwheel.getColor();

  relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
showbutton.setTextColor(color);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

**SECOND ACTIVITY OF AMAZING FACTS-AMAZING NOTE**

```
package com.example.user.amazingfacts;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by User on 09-10-2017.
 */

public class Amazingnote {
    public String getFact() {
        String[] facts = {"In 1889, the Queen of Italy, Margherita Savoy, ordered the first pizza delivery",
                " You can buy eel flavored ice cream in Japan",
                "Although the bobcat is rarely seen, it is the most common wildcat in North America",
                " A cat's tail contains nearly 10 percent of all the bones in its body",
                "The term astronaut comes from Greek words that mean star and sailor",
                "The calcium in our bones and the iron in our blood come from ancient explosions of giant stars",
                "The Nile crocodile can hold its breath underwater for up to 2 hours while waiting for prey",
                "Jellyfish, or jellies as scientists call them, are not fish. They have no brain, no heart, and no bones",
                " Some people used to believe that kissing a donkey could relieve a toothache.",
                " Because the speed of Earth's rotation changes over time, a day in the age of dinosaurs was just 23 hours long",
                "Hummingbirds' wings can beat 200 times a second.",
                "There are more than 1,200 water parks in North America.",
                "A seahorse can move its eyes in opposite directions—all the better to scan the water for food and predators.",
                " To cook an egg, a sidewalk needs to be 158°F."

        };

        Random randomGenerator=new Random();
        int randomnumber=randomGenerator.nextInt(facts.length);
        return facts[randomnumber];

    }
}
```

**THIRD ACTIVITY OF AMAZING FACTS-COLORWHEEL**

```
package com.example.user.amazingfacts;

import android.graphics.Color;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by User on 10-10-2017.
 */

public class Colorwheel
{
  //Fields or Member Variables -Properties abou the object
    private String[] colors = {
          "#39add1",//light blue
          "#3079ab",//dark blue
          "#c25975",//mauve
          "#e15258",//red


    };
    //Methods-Actions the object can take
    int getColor()
    {

    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
    int randomnumber=randomGenerator.nextInt(colors.length);
     int color= Color.parseColor(colors[randomnumber]) ;
    return color ;

}
}
```

This is a small application named Amazing facts.It uses two `Text views` and only one button.
    The first `Text view` is not that much of important one"Do you know?".This is the first `Text view`.
    When the user clicks the button the content of the second `Text View` and the background color of the application changes.That is my idea.
I successfully build the application  using build function but I tried to install the application on my android phone.The app is stopping when I clicked the button.I understand that there are some issues in the `on click` property.I totally removed the second class "color wheel" from the `*`on click`*` then the app is working.Why did the app is not loading the methods of two objects in a single `On click`? Why I am not able to change the Text View and background color ` simultaneously?

Comment: Your `relativeLayout` is not initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first part of your Main activity to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView showtext;
private Button showbutton;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private Amazingnote Amazingnote=new Amazingnote();
private Colorwheel colorwheel=new Colorwheel();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main_activity); 
        .
        .
        .
```

your layout is not initialized so you are trying to change the color of an object that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You can't do that at that point, because your Activity did not set a content view yet

Comment: This update should work. Thanks @0xDEADC0DE. Totally missed that one.

Comment: @HarikrishnanJayachandran No problem, happy to help.